# In Electronjs <webview> guest page can not get cookie by document.cookie

Tags: electron, electron-vue

in guest page

```
<script>
console.log(document.cookie)
// ""
</script>
```

But in Developer Tools` Application Cookies has values.

Comment: Are the cookies set as HttpOnly cookies? (You should see this in the Developer Tools.) If so, they are only sent with http requests to the server and are inaccessible via JS (this adds an extra layer of security, and can be used to protect session cookies and the likes).

Comment: I sure not cookies set as HttpOnly cookies